# Content Type Content Theme Template

Tags: theming, nodes

Is it possible to make a template based on node content?
For instance, is it possible to *page--[node-type]--%.tpl.php* or *block--[content-type].tpl.php* or *page--[content-type]--%*.  I tried *node--[content-type].tpl.php* but to no avail.  When I use the [theme developer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer), it shows me that my content is being created as a *'block.tpl.php'* template.

What I want to do is theme the content of node name 'vehicle'. I want to put custom headings, styles and classes for divs in, and display suite is not giving me these options.  Any other suggestions would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are right node--[content-type].tpl.php is what you are looking for ,, but you need to get the fields values which can be done with `print_r($node)` inside the tpl file.

clear your cache to be sure to see the result.